# Valgrind shows Leak_DefinitelyLost even after releasing the pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, thread-safety, unique-ptr

In some file called Tasks.h, I have the following function :-

```
void source_thread_func(BlockingQueue<Task> &bq, int num_ints)
{
std::cout<<"On source thread func"<<std::endl; // Debug
    for (int i = 1; i <= num_ints; i++)
    {
        //Valgrind does not like this
        std::unique_ptr<Task> task(new Task(i, i == num_ints));
    std::cout<<"Pushing value = "<<i<<std::endl; // Debug
        bq.push(task);
        Task* tp = task.release();
        assert (task.get() == nullptr);
        delete tp;
    }
}
```

and the relevant push function in the BlockingQueue is

```
    void push(std::unique_ptr<T>& item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        queue_.push(std::move(item));
        mlock.unlock();
        cond_.notify_one();
    }
```

But, this still causes a leak when checking with Valgrind. Could you tell me where the leak is?  I am attaching a screenshot of the valgrind result. How more can I delete this pointer?
[image]

Edit : Task doesn't contain a  copy constructor (I've deleted it)

### Further Edit : full example

```
//Tasks.h
namespace threadsx
{
class Task
{
public:
    Task(int val, bool sentinel = false)
    {
        m_val = val;
        Sent = sentinel;
    }

    int m_val;
    int Sent;

    //disable copying
    Task (const Task&) = delete;
};


void source_thread_func(BlockingQueue<Task> &bq, int num_ints)
{
std::cout<<"On source thread func"<<std::endl; // Debug
    for (int i = 1; i <= num_ints; i++)
    {

        std::unique_ptr<Task> task(new Task(i, i == num_ints));
        std::cout<<"Pushing value = "<<i<<std::endl; // Debug
        bq.push(task);
        Task* tp = task.release();
        assert (task.get() == nullptr);
        delete tp;
    }
}
}
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
///BlockingQueue.h
namespace threadsx
{
 // -- Custom Blocking Q
template <typename T>
class BlockingQueue
{
private:
    std::queue<std::unique_ptr<T>> queue_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cond_;

    void push(std::unique_ptr<T>& item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        queue_.push(std::move(item));
        mlock.unlock();
        cond_.notify_one();
    }

    BlockingQueue()=default;
    BlockingQueue(const BlockingQueue&) = delete;            // disable copying
    BlockingQueue& operator=(const BlockingQueue&) = delete; // disable assignment

};
}
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
//main.cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

int num_ints = 30;
int threshold = 5;

threadsx::BlockingQueue<threadsx::Task> q;
std::vector<int> t;

std::thread source_thread(threadsx::source_thread_func, std::ref(q), num_ints);

if(source_thread.joinable())
    source_thread.join();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish here. If what you tried worked the way you seem to intend, you would be `delete`ing the task that you just pushed into the queue. What would you expect the queue to do with the task you just deleted? Did you assume that you are passing/deleting a copy? (You explicitly prevent any kind of copies with `unique_ptr`...)

Comment: @eerorika I have added an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allowed to delete the raw task, since the ownership is no longer yours.

```
void source_thread_func(BlockingQueue<Task>& bq, int num_ints)
{
    std::cout<<"On source thread func"<<std::endl; // Debug
    for (int i = 1; i <= num_ints; i++)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<Task> task = std::make_unique<Task>(i, i == num_ints);
        bq.push(std::move(task));
    }
}
```

Blocking Queue:

```
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <deque>

template <typename T>
class BlockingQueue {
public:
    void push(std::unique_ptr<T>&& item)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        queue_.push_back(std::move(item));
        cond_.notify_one();
    }

    std::unique_ptr<T> pop()
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> mlock(mutex_);
        if (queue_.empty()) {
            cond_.wait(mlock, [this] { return !queue_.empty(); });
        }
        std::unique_ptr<T> ret = std::unique_ptr<T>(queue_.front().release());
        queue_.pop_front();
        return ret;
    }

private:
    std::deque<std::unique_ptr<T>> queue_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
    std::condition_variable cond_;
};
```

If you want to spare yourself the headache of std::move, use shared_ptr instead

Comment: Without modifications to pop(..) and only modifying the signature of push, and changes in source_thread_func(..), I still get this valgrind mem leak.

Answer (score 2):

The program that you show does not `delete` the `Task` that was allocated. `push` moves the ownership away from `task`, so `tp` is always null.

The ownership of the resource is transferred into `queue_`, and how that pointer is leaked (assuming valgrind is correct) is not shown in the example program.

---

Few quality issues:

- As pointed out in the comments, it is usually a bad design to pass unique pointers by non-const reference. Pass by value when you intend to transfer ownership.

  > I've deleted the copy constructor on Task. Would passing by value still work?

  Whether `Task` is copyable is irrelevant to whether a unique pointer can be passed by value. Unique pointer is movable regardless of the type of the pointed object, and therefore can be passed by value.
- Don't release from a unique pointer just in order to delete the memory. Simply let the unique pointer go out of scope - its destructor takes care of deletion.

Comment: Nevermind my earlier comment. Taking a `unique_ptr` by reference and then moving from it is just plain horrible. I would advise to just take `unique_ptr` by value (so the caller has to clearly move and thus give up ownership).

Comment: I've deleted the copy constructor on Task. Would passing by value still work?

Comment: It seems like the compiler does not like me passing the unique_ptr by value (its still trying to call the copy constructor of Task). I have a new edit with the entire snippet. Please have a look at it, and let me know?